# What's difference between concatenated and sequential models in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tried to solve XOR task with different approaches. The first one with using of sequential model:

```
result = Sequential()
result.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))
result.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))
ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.1, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
result.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss=_loss_tensor)
```

Based on test data:

```
X = np.array([ [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0] ])
Y_train.append(0)
Y_train.append(1)
Y_train.append(1)
Y_train.append(0)
```

I train the model and accuracy will be about 1.

If I try to solve the same task in the following way:

```
first_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='x1')
input_dense = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(first_input)
second_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='x2')
second_dense = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(second_input)

merge_one = concatenate([input_dense, second_dense])
merge_one_dense2 = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', )(merge_one)
merge_one_dense3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(merge_one_dense2)

result = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs=merge_one_dense3)
ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.1, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
result.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss=_loss_tensor)
```

with following test data:

```
X1 = np.array([ [1], [0], [1], [0] ])
X2 = np.array([ [1], [1], [0], [0] ])
Y_train.append(0)
Y_train.append(1)
Y_train.append(1)
Y_train.append(0)
```

I got accuracy about 0.5.

Visually the both models look the same for me:
the first model: [image: the first model]

the second model: [image: the second model]

What have I missed or haven't considered?

**UPD:**
After some investigations I can say that there are not any difference between these models. The reason why answers are different is the fact that I use different (random) initial conditions. If starts models simulation with the same initial conditions results will be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second model is more complex than the first model, maybe you should train for more steps.

here is my code, the acc is simple_acc: 0.7923, complex_acc: 0.7244. you can fine-tune it yourself.

```
#coding: utf-8
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input,Dense,merge
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.optimizers import Adagrad

def simple_model():
    result = Sequential()
    result.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))
    result.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,), activation='sigmoid'))
    ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.001, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    result.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss='hinge')
    return result

def complex_model():
    first_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='x1')
    input_dense = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(first_input)
    second_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='x2')
    second_dense = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(second_input)

    merge_one = merge([input_dense, second_dense],mode='concat',concat_axis=1)
    merge_one_dense2 = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid', )(merge_one)
    merge_one_dense3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', )(merge_one_dense2)

    result = Model(inputs=[first_input, second_input], outputs=merge_one_dense3)
    ada_grad = Adagrad(lr=0.001, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
    result.compile(optimizer=ada_grad, loss='hinge')
    return result

def simple_data():
    X = np.array([ [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0] ])
    Y = np.array([ [0], [1], [1], [0] ])
    return X,Y

def complex_data():
    X1 = np.array([ [1], [0], [1], [0] ])
    X2 = np.array([ [1], [1], [0], [0] ])
    Y = np.array([ [0], [1], [1], [0] ])
    return [X1,X2],Y

def test_simple_model():
    model = simple_model()
    X,Y = simple_data()
    model.summary()
    model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=4,epochs=1000,verbose=1,validation_data=(X,Y))
    score = model.evaluate(X,Y,verbose=0)
    return score

def test_complex_model():
    model = complex_model()
    X,Y = complex_data()
    model.summary()
    model.fit(X,Y,batch_size=4,epochs=1000,verbose=1,validation_data=(X,Y))
    score = model.evaluate(X,Y,verbose=0)
    return score

def main():
    simple_acc = test_simple_model()
    complex_acc = test_complex_model()
    print 'simple_acc: %.4f' % simple_acc
    print 'complex_acc: %.4f' % complex_acc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I do not think that it's a complex model. It has only 4 neurons and I already do 3000 on epochs.

Comment: maybe you should paste all of your code here, so others can double check it.